# How to get a control inside a wpf datagrid

Tags: wpf, silverlight, wpfdatagrid

i have a data-grid with several rows. Inside every row the first column is a button. I have the row index. Let say my row index is 7. Now i want to get the button inside the row 7 and changed its content.

How do i get this button control inside a particular row of a datagrid and change its value?

Comment: Have you tried something ? can you post those codes here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps, the below code solve your problem.

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Button Click="ShowHideDetails">Details</Button>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
  </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

In Codebehind C# access the control

```
private void ShowHideDetails(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            // You can access the button and do whateve the changes you want
            Button objMyButton = null;
            if (sender is Button)
            {
                objMyButton = (sender as Button);

            }

            //You can access the parent object which means corresponding DataGridRow and do whatever you want

            for (var vis = sender as Visual; vis != null; vis = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(vis) as Visual)
                if (vis is DataGridRow)
                {
                    var row = (DataGridRow)vis;                 
                    break;
                }
        }
```